# How to split the code over several lines in R Studio

Tags: r

I have the following code that identifies which variables from two columns in dataframe 'prep' are not in a certain column of dataframe 'results':

```
unique(c(as.character(prep$player1), as.character (prep$player2))) [!unique(c(as.character(prep$player1), as.character (prep$player2)))%in% results$names]
```

It works well when it is on one line. But I want it to run at least over two lines to make it easier to see it. I tried

```
unique(c(as.character(prep$player1), as.character (prep$player2)))+
[!unique(c(as.character(prep$player1), as.character (prep$player2)))%in% results$names]
```

and

```
 unique(c(as.character(prep$player1), as.character (prep$player2)))
+[!unique(c(as.character(prep$player1), as.character (prep$player2)))%in% results$names]
```

I get the error: `unexpected '['` in "[" and  `unexpected '[' in "+["`
Can you help me break the code. Thanks

Comment: The `+` at the end is not need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to run iin multiple lines, use, just split after the `[` (also the `+` may be the artifact from copying the code from console)

```
unique(c(as.character(prep$player1), as.character (prep$player2)))[
  !unique(c(as.character(prep$player1),
       as.character (prep$player2)))%in% results$names]
```

---

In `R 4.1.0`, we can also use `|>` for chaining

```
unique(c(as.character(prep$player1), as.character (prep$player2))) |>
   {\(dt) dt[!unique(c(as.character(prep$player1), 
            as.character (prep$player2)))%in% results$names]}()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I tried initially without "+" but the [ was in my second line. Then I found a suggestion to use +

Comment: @Vasile the `+` is from the console symbol suggesting that the code expression is not complete..  If the `[` is second line.  the first line expression is completed before the `[`.  Or you could also use `%>%`

Comment: thanks, akrun. Your answers are always helpful and amazingly quick.

Comment: @Vasile is this a data.table code or not.  I couldn't underestand why you are using `prep$` inside the subset again

Comment: I am not versed in the terminology. So I am not sure if  a data.frame the same as a data.table.  When I run is.data.frame(prep), it gives me true.

Comment: @Vasile that is fine.  I didn't know whether you were doing this on a vector or data.frame or data.table.  thanks